# Laravel 5.3, ECHO & Pusher, export Pusher secret to .env

Tags: php, environment-variables, laravel-5.3, pusher, laravel-echo

I'm using Laravel 5.3 with Pusher and all is working well.

However I would like to export my Pusher credentials to `.env`. Or anywhere else so that I can easily use different Pusher apps on my dev/staging/production environments.

This is my setup:

import Echo from "laravel-echo"

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'myKey', //development key
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true
});
```

In `gulpfile.js` I have

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.webpack('echo.js','./resources/assets/js/');
});
```

then

```
mix.scripts([
    'echo.js',
    ...
], 'public/js/all.js');
```

And finally in my view:

```
let myRoom = 'room-user-'+'{{ Auth::user()->id }}';
    Echo.private(myRoom)
        .listen('MyEvent', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
```

As I said this is all working well.

My problem is the `key: 'myKey', //development key`. Is there a simple way to use Laravel environment variable `env('PUSHER_KEY')` here? Because as things are now I need to use the same Pusher App in my development, staging and production.

Also my `config/broadcasting` is

```
'connections' => [

    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_CLUSTER','eu'),
            'encrypted' => true,
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [laravel-elixir-env](https://github.com/appstract/laravel-elixir-env) library as:

**gulpfile.js**

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-env');
...
elixir(function(mix) {
   mix.webpack('echo.js','./resources/assets/js/');
});
...
```

**echo.js**

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.PUSHER_KEY,
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true
});
```

**.env**

```
...
PUSHER_KEY=my_pusher_key
...
```